# Some e-mails not delivered to ros-users?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Comparing its [lurker](https://code.ros.org/lurker/list/ros-users.html) and [nabble.com](http://ros-users.122217.n3.nabble.com/), I noticed a couple of emails only appear on nabble. I noticed at least these titles are missing:

- A new repository in fuerte to index by zhuangyan Apr 08
- A new repository in fuerte to index by dbb Apr 03

And I haven't received these e-mails in my mailbox. I'm not sure what nabble.com does either but why is this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60254/some-e-mails-not-delivered-to-ros-users?/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2013-04-08

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That's a problem (or maybe a misconception) with Nabble. It pretends to be a forum where you can actively post instead of writing an email to the mailing list. Nabble will then try to send a corresponding email to the list.

But the mailing list will only accept email from subscribed members. Someone posting through Nabble may not be a member, and the mail will bounce.

Maybe a big warning like on http://www.pcl-users.org could help?

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2013-04-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know that I had to whitelist ros-users in GMail because it was classifying a LOT of emails from ros-users as spam. Maybe that's what's happening.

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2013-04-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-04-08**:
Well, in this case I'm comparing `lurker` and `nabble`. My Gmail hasn't even received those emails in spam box.